# How to write non-returning postgresql CTEs in Jooq

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, jooq

In Jooq, I can use the `DSL#name(...)` method to write CTEs, including INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE queries that have a `RETURNING` clause

e.g.

```
name("my_cte").as(
    update(MY_TABLE)
        // ...
    .returning(MY_TABLE.ID)
)
```

But I get a type mismatch at compile time if I remove the `.returning(...)` part

Is there a way around that ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Basically, I want to have a single statement that contains data modifying CTEs and a final SELECT, but I don't actually need a RETURNING clause in the upsert/delete CTEs

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't trust this construct of PostgreSQL. While it *probably* executes statements in lexical order, if you (accidentally) create a dependency between statements, it might reorder them arbitrarily. Better to use an anonymous block or a stored function, in my opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible in jOOQ. You must supply a `RETURNING` clause for a DML statement to be usable in a CTE. You could try creating a feature request for this, but I don't think this will be prioritised. The utility of this approach seems negligible, compared to a much cleaner approach where you'd use a stored procedure for the same thing, either written in native PL/pgSQL or with jOOQ's [procedural language support](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/procedural-statements/).